# Twilio - How to get request-inspector on my application?

Tags: twilio

I've set up a status callback event and I would like to retrieve some events that were fired by gather. Is it possible to use "requests-inspector" based on my CallSid or "request-inspector" is avaible only though Twilio Console?

Tyvm

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. You should set an `action` attribute on your `<Gather>` to a URL that will receive an HTTP request with the result of the `<Gather>`. Are you asking about the inspector for the TwiML returned throughout a call flow? And whether you can access that via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our understanding after conversations with Twilio, it is NOT possible to access the Requests Inspector programmatically.